Tcolorbox doesn't work well with only left side rule with rounded corners
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}


\begin{document}





\newtcolorbox{mybox}{
enhanced jigsaw,
boxrule=0pt,
leftrule=4pt,
arc=6pt,
}
\begin{mybox}
  Hello World
\end{mybox}



\end{document}

This is the result in zathura pdf viewer:

and this is the result with chrome:

Why is the border still here? If I don't use "enhanced jigsaw", it happens in zathura too.

It is a known problem: the line width is zero, but in some viewers it still shows. If you zoom into the document, you will see that the line has no real width.

Is there any alternative solution using mdframed?

You could use frame hidden to totally remove the frame drawing and then draw your border using overlay and TikZ.
In case your box goes on many pages you can adapt my code using overlay first, overlay middle and overlay last, respectively for setting the TikZ code the first, the middle, and the last pages.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}{
enhanced jigsaw,
boxrule=0pt,
leftrule=4pt,
arc=6pt,
}

\newtcolorbox{myboxb}{
    enhanced jigsaw,
    frame hidden,
    boxrule=0pt,
    leftrule=4pt,
    arc=6pt,
    overlay={\path[fill=black!70] 
      ([xshift=10pt]frame.north west) to[out=180, in=90] 
      ([xshift=4pt, yshift=-6pt]frame.north west) --
      ([xshift=4pt, yshift=6pt]frame.south west) to[out=-90, in=180]
      ([xshift=10pt]frame.south west) --
      ([xshift=6pt]frame.south west) to[out=180, in=-90]
      ([yshift=6pt]frame.south west) --
      ([yshift=-6pt]frame.north west) to[out=90, in=180]
      ([xshift=6pt]frame.north west) --
      ([xshift=10pt]frame.north west)
      ;}
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{mybox}
  Your original box
\end{mybox}
\begin{myboxb}
  My modified box
\end{myboxb}
\end{document}


As you can see from the image, in your original box the frame is still visible, in my box it is not.

thanks, it worked

@JawadHameemChowdhury You're welcome! Thank you for accepting my answer!
